# react - prevent video from going fullscreen on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, video

I am making a web app with video playback and custom controls: a Next Video button and a Previous Video Button. My component looks like this:

```
const videos = [
    'https://d3t1nqlebka5eu.cloudfront.net/videos3/82818a63-1972-4e39-b296-9cd3b85b0b39.mp4',
    'https://d3t1nqlebka5eu.cloudfront.net/videos3/dd4dd6c5-95b7-41c2-b131-7b62392ad1b5.mp4',
    'https://d3t1nqlebka5eu.cloudfront.net/videos3/29812506-e67d-4cab-b2b3-82461a4eadf1.mp4',
]

function App() {

    const [videoIndex, setVideoIndex] = useState(0);
    const h1Ref = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);

    return (
        <div>
            <DivButton onClick={() => {
                setVideoIndex(getPrevIndex(videoIndex));
                h1Ref.current!.load();
            }}>
                Prev
            </DivButton>
            {' '}
            <DivButton onClick={() => {
                setVideoIndex(getNextIndex(videoIndex));
                h1Ref.current!.load();
            }}>
                Next
            </DivButton>
            <div>
                <video id="video_player" autoPlay muted loop playsinline preload="" ref={h1Ref}>
                    <source id="video_player_source" src={videos[videoIndex]} type="video/mp4"/>
                </video>

            </div>

        </div>
    );
}
```

The problem is this: when I click Next or Prev buttons, the videos do switch between one another, but after every switch they are entering fullscreen mode on iOS. I don't need that, I need my controls around the video being played.

Is there a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you already found an answer but for other people looking at this in the future, I suspect the issue was your capitalization of `playsinline` - in React you have to provide it as `playsInline` in order for it to be applied correctly, but that prop should prevent iOS from forcing videos into fullscreen when they start playing.